# What does the last line of the Beacon of Luck spell mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The [beacon of luck](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beacon-of-luck/) spell has two effects.

Effect one is a +2 sacred bonus to saves, and effect two is the ability to roll twice for a save (before roll(s) are made). The last line says:

> Once a creature benefits from the beacon of luck in this way, it cannot gain the benefit of this spell for 24 hours.

The spell doesn't say it's dismissed when used this way, so its full duration should still be in effect. Does it mean that only the roll effect cant be used multiple times (even with multiple castings), or is even the bonus to saving throws disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of the spell [*beacon of luck*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beacon-of-luck/) says

> You send out a burst of luck with a 30-foot radius centered around you. While the *beacon of luck* is in effect, you gain a +2 sacred bonus on all saving throws. As an immediate action before a saving throw is made, allies within the area can choose to benefit from this luck, rolling twice for a saving throw and taking the better result. Once a creature benefits from the *beacon of luck* in this way [i.e. by rolling twice], it cannot gain the benefit of this spell for 24 hours.

When the caster, due to the spell's effect, takes an immediate action to roll a saving throw twice, the caster doesn't *stop* benefiting from the spell: the spell doesn't end and the spell's entry of ***Duration*** 1 min./level continues normally. This means that, yes, after the reroll's used, the caster continues to receive the spell's benefit of a +2 sacred bonus on saving throws until the spell's duration expires.

However, once the reroll's been used and after the *beacon* spell's duration has expired,  the caster *can't* receive "the benefit" of the next or later *beacon of hope* spell in the same 24-hour period (no matter who casts the *beacon* spell). Although the spell's description uses the singular *benefit* as if the spell had only one, *Pathfinder* frequently uses the word *benefit* to encompass the entirety of an effect. (For example, [feats](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/#feats-general) are listed as having a (singular) benefit no matter how many different effects the feat has.) With this in mind, this GM would rule that the spell's benefit includes *both* the saving throw reroll *and* the sacred bonus on saving throws.